# How to authenticate with LDAP using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm using Mr. Sam J Levy PHP LDAP authentication [script](https://samjlevy.com/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/). I'm not familiar with Microsoft Active Directory at all. So I'm not sure what I have to put in for `$ldap_user_group = "WebUsers";` and `$ldap_manager_group = "WebManagers";`. For my company's AD the user's accounts are divided under different departments and locations. I understand the rest of the script, I'm just not sure of how am I supposed to get to the WebUsers and WebManagers. Any help is appreciated.

This is the full script:

```
<?php
// Initialize session
session_start();

function authenticate($user, $password) {
if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;

// Active Directory server
$ldap_host = "192.158.16.73";

// Active Directory DN OU=Accounts,DC=DMM,DC=JED,DC=RUH
$ldap_dn = "CN=Some Name,OU=IT,OU=Office Users,OU=RUH,OU=Accounts,DC=Company,DC=com";

// Active Directory user group
$ldap_user_group = "WebUsers";

// Active Directory manager group
$ldap_manager_group = "WebManagers";

// Domain, for purposes of constructing $user Company.com
$ldap_usr_dom = '@Company.com';

// connect to active directory
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
    // valid
    // check presence in groups
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    ldap_unbind($ldap);

    // check groups
    foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
        // is manager, break loop
        if(strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) { $access = 2; break; }

        // is user
        if(strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) $access = 1;
    }

    if($access != 0) {
        // establish session variables
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
        return true;
    } else {
        // user has no rights
        return false;
    }

} else {
    // invalid name or password
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have a look into your companies LDAP/AD with a tool like Apache DS or jXplorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is using those 2 variables in a check against the $entries that come back from ldap_get_entries.  He is trying to determine if the user is a "manager" or a "user"... this part may be specific to his enterprise... and you might be able to get by without going this far.... Just comment those variables out, and also comment out the section after // check groups

You can then examine $entries to see what it looks like for your enterprise and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Wes for replying. I actually would like to check if the user is a "manager" or a "user" but in my company's AD we don't have a "manager" and a "user" folders with users under them, should we do that ? Also if I comment  that part out I get an error "failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights".

Comment: I don't think I can help much... but I can say that if you comment that stuff out you should return true from that method because it will be getting past the bind so that would mean the username and password are correct.